# Selenium: switching to main window after popup window closed by user

Tags: python, selenium, popupwindow

I have an app where the user can click button and popup window shows up. Then, after clicking submit button in this popup window, the window gets closed and the user continues work in the main window.

I want to be able to select elements using selenium in the main window, then select elements in the popup and after popup get closed, again in the main window. Any ideas how would I do this?

**EDIT:**
Here is my code. I'm using [django-addanother](http://django-addanother.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create form with popups. Main form is Robject form. Rest forms are popups.

```
class CreateRobjectView(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'robjects/create_robject.html'
    success_url = "/projects/proj_1/robjects/"
    raise_exception = True
    permission_required = ['projects.can_visit_project',
                           'projects.can_modify_project']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        Name.objects.filter(robjects=None).delete()
        RobjectFile.objects.filter(robjects=None).delete()
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        robject = Robject.objects.last()
        Name.objects.filter(robjects=None).delete()
        RobjectFile.objects.filter(robjects=None).delete()
        return redirect("robjects_list", self.args[0])

    def get_initial(self):
        return {
            "create_by": self.request.user,
            "project": Project.objects.get(name=self.args[0])
        }

    def get_form_class(self):
        form = modelform_factory(Robject, form=ModelForm, exclude=["modify_by"],
                                 widgets={
            'names': AddAnotherWidgetWrapper(
                forms.SelectMultiple,
                reverse_lazy('add_name', args=[self.args[0]]),
            ),

            'files': AddAnotherWidgetWrapper(
                forms.SelectMultiple,
                reverse_lazy('add_file', args=[self.args[0]]),
            ),

            'tags': AddAnotherWidgetWrapper(
                forms.SelectMultiple,
                reverse_lazy('add_tag', args=[self.args[0]]),
            ),
            'project': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'create_by': forms.HiddenInput()
        })
        return form

    def get_permission_object(self):
        project = Project.objects.get(name=self.args[0])
        return project

class CreateNameView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreatePopupMixin, CreateView):
    model = Name
    fields = "__all__"
    template_name = 'robjects/create_name.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        return {"project": Project.objects.get(name=self.args[0])}

    def get_form(self):
        form = super(CreateNameView, self).get_form()
        form.fields['project'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        return form

class RobjectFileCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreatePopupMixin, CreateView):
    model = RobjectFile
    fields = ['_file', 'description']
    template_name = 'robjects/create_robject_file.html'


class TagCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreatePopupMixin, CreateView):
    model = Tag
    fields = ['name', "project"]
    template_name = 'robjects/create_tag.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        return {"project": Project.objects.get(name=self.args[0])}

    def get_form(self):
        form = super(TagCreateView, self).get_form()
        form.fields['project'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        return form
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in browser driver. I solved it by switching from Firefox driver to Chrome driver.

Answer (score 1):

Once you click on the button you must switch to the pop up and regardless of weather your pop getting closed automatically or not you need to switch back. Try below

```
        //Before clicking on the button which opens pop up, capture the parent window handle.
                    parent = driver.current_window_handle

        //Click on button

                            time.sleep(1)

       //Switch to the latest window

                        for winhandle in driver.window_handles:
                            print "Handle = ",handle
                            driver.switch_to_window(handle);
                            print driver.title

      //Click on submit and wait & switch back to parent window

                        time.sleep(2)
                        driver.switch_to_window(parent);
```

Comment: Problem is that when selenium clicks submit button and popup closes, tests are suspended. This means they dont breake and don't go further. No error, no feedback, nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878383/selenium-django-tests-stops-when-testing-popup-window